# How to publish message dynamically to channel(my custom domain) in pub/sub with spring data redis

Tags: publish-subscribe, spring-data-redis, lettuce

In my **RedisMessageListenerContainer** I have registered the channel like below. Both publish message to that specific and subscribe are working good. But I need to publish message dynamically to my channels( to my custom domain should be the channel name). This channel should be passed dynamically. Below

Below is my RedisMessageListenerContainer.

```
 public RedisMessageListenerContainer redisContainer(final RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        RedisMessageListenerContainer container
                = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
        container.addMessageListener(messageListener(), channelTopic());
        final List<ChannelTopic> channelTopics = new ArrayList<>();
        container.addMessageListener(messageListener(),channelTopics);
        return container;
    }
```

With the above config I could only publis/subscribe message to a specific channel but I need it in a more dynamic way.

Can you please help on it.

Thank you,

Syamala.